# Get tabs to go to the right?

Tags: html, css

Here's what i've done so far:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

/* Tabs */
#navlist {
        padding: 3px 0;
        margin-left: 0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #778;
        font: bold 12px Verdana, sans-serif;
        /* WARNING: when using font-size/font-family instead of font, 
           do not forget to set line-height:normal otherwise 1px more is shown
           between tabs and their bottom line in IE8 and FF3.6 */
}

#navlist li {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        display: inline;
}

#navlist li a {
        padding: 3px 0.5em;
        margin-left: 0px;
        border: 1px solid #778;
        border-bottom: none;
        background: #DDE;
        text-decoration: none;
}

#navlist li a:link { color: #448; }
#navlist li a:visited { color: #667; }

#navlist li a:hover {
        color: #000;
        background: #AAE;
        border-color: #227;
}

#navlist li a#current {
        background: white;
        border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
                <div id="navcontainer">
                        <ul id="navlist">
                                    <li><a id="current" href="#">Col1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Col2</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Col3</a></li>
                            </ul>
                </div>
</body>
</html>​
```

And it's saved to http://jsbin.com/uvako3/2. Thanks for your help

Comment: +1 Great example of simple working HTML+CSS to make tabs. I adde a small comment in your code becase I banged my head 2 hours before discovering what wa the issue in IE8/FF3.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `text-align: right;` to the `#navlist` css.

*Explanation:* You are making your list items *inline* elements. That makes them follow the general rules that apply to text. So by simply setting the text align, you are specifying where inline elements are aligned to.